# Is there any OpenCV build for CentOS 7 with Java support?

Tags: java, opencv, centos7

I need to use OpenCV version 4.5.1 in Java. My platform is CentOS 7 and there is only OpenCV version 2.4 on the official repositories (these package: `opencv`, `opencv-core`, `opencv-devel`, `opencv-devel-docs`, `opencv-python` in base repo; Notice there is no Java wrapper). Is there any build that will meet my needs?

I know I can build OpenCV from source and enable java support (and build `opencv_java451.so`), **BUT** it would take a long time and also require too many tools to be installed beforehand.

On the official OpenCV website, there is a [page](https://pullrequest.opencv.org/#/summary/) called *build farm* but I do not know what exactly that this.

This the the error that I get when I try to run the project:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java451 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
```

I mentioned version 4.5.1 but I think some older version (like 3.x.x) would also do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Origami (jvm wrapper for opencv) now supports 4.5.1.
(I am the author)

You can download the opencv for java template from:

https://github.com/hellonico/opencv-java-template

and run with:

```
mvn exec:java
```